# quarkus qute: iteration metadata count, hasNext, ... not working

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-qute

When making the tutorial

https://kubebyexample.com/en/learning-paths/developing-quarkus-kubernetes/templating-qute-templating-engine/rendering-periodic

the following error appears

```
quarkus.qute.TemplateException: Entry "count" not found in the data map in expression {count} in template reports/v1/report_01.json.template on line 5
```

Configuration: Quarkus 2.6.1.Final, surefire-plugin 3.0.0-M5, compiler-plugin 3.8.1

When removing the "count" from the json-template, it works perfect

I tried also another example (from Sebastian Daschner)

https://github.com/sdaschner/quarkus-playground/tree/qute-example/src/main/java/com/sebastian_daschner/entries

This works perfect with 1.3.1.Final but after updating to 2.6.1.Final the same error occurs.

Can you pls help me.
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  From the documentation:

> However, the keys cannot be used directly.
> Instead, a prefix is used to avoid possible collisions with variables
> from the outer scope. By default, the alias of an iterated element
> suffixed with an underscore is used as a prefix. For example, the
> hasNext key must be prefixed with it_ inside an {#each} section:
> {it_hasNext}.

I had to update the `{count}` to `{it_count}` or `{item_count}` for my application after upgrading.

```
{#each items}
  {it_count}. {it.name} 
  {#if it_hasNext}<br>{/if} 
{/each}
```

Similarly for a for loop:

```
{#for item in items}
  {item_count}. {item.name} 
  {#if item_hasNext}<br>{/if} 
{/each}
```

[Quarkus reference](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#loop_section)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I didn't notice this paragraph in the docs. Sorry - will be more thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 0):

For the record - this breaking change got introduced in 2.5.0 and is documented in the [migration guide](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-2.5#iteration-metadata-prefix). It's always good to read the migration guides! ;-)